# Why is CMake trying to install my target to an absolute path?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake, cpack

I have:

```
install(TARGETS MyPlugin DESTINATION bin)
```

MyPlugin is a library target. On Windows 8.1 CMake (3.4.0-rc2) tries to install my library to C:/Program Files/[PROJECT]/bin/ no matter what I do. How can I force it install locally so that I can make a package with CPack? I'm a bit confused as this has worked before without any problems.

CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX doesn't seem to have any effect on this.

Comment: Very old question, but: did you set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` *environment* variable instead of the CMake variable?